# Import excel data into custom table

Tags: kentico

I am using Kentico v10.0, I have 400+ records that needed to be enter.

Currently the data was stored using custom table. Is that a way for me to import all the data from an excel file? I think no one likes to do data entry jobs...

So by using the Kentico Import Toolkit is able to achieve what I request.

But I found another problems which there are many empty fields like the picture below:

[image]

I have no idea what to put as the default value while importing, so i decided to leave it empty.

Will it affect anythings in the future if these fields are `NULL`?

Or there is a way to set the default value from the kentico itself? So I don't need to bother the default value while importing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Kentico Import Toolkit](https://docs.kentico.com/k10/external-utilities/kentico-import-toolkit).  You can import into your site directly from the Excel sheet.  You can also use SQL Server Management Studio to import the custom table data.  I'd not recommend using SSMS for anything other than custom table data though.

Comment: I have some add on to the question, can you please help? Thx!

Comment: What are your questions?

Comment: I edited this question by add on:

So by using the Kentico Import Toolkit is able to achieve what I request.

But I found another problems which there are many empty fields like the picture below:

enter image description here

I have no idea what to put as the default value while importing, so i decided to leave it empty.

Will it affect anythings in the future if these fields are NULL?


Or there is a way to set the default value from the kentico itself? So I don't need to bother the default value while importing.

Comment: There is no issue with leaving those empty.  They will be updated if someone updates the record in Kentico.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest in this order.

1. Kentico import Toolkit. Very versatile and can be used for other things too. You don't have to worry about those null values unless those values are supposed to be mandatory non-null values.
2. Second option would be to connect to Kentico's DB using SSMS and import the data in the desired table.

Comment: Aren't those the same answers I provided?  Why provide a duplicate answer?

Comment: Apologies Brenden, I included SoYuJe concern about null values in my answer. I should have used comments. Do you want me to delete my answer?